# How to extract a string in csh?

Tags: string, shell, csh

I would like to extract a string as below:

```
setenv VARIABLE /opt/Application/File/Version22
```

I want to display only

```
File/Version22
```

on screen. It means `/opt/Application/` is always the prefix. I want to display the rest of the string. How do I do it in csh?

Regards

Comment: Is the prefix always "/opt/Application"? If so, why not use `sed`: `echo $VARIABLE | sed 's#/opt/Application/##g'`

Comment: how can we combine it with the result of `find. . -type  d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've updated the question (thank you for that), it's clear that you always want to remove the `/opt/Application` prefix.

The most straightforward way to do that, which will work in any shell, is:

```
echo $VARIABLE | sed 's|^/opt/Application/||'
```

(It's usual to use `/` as a delimiter for replacements like this, but you can use any punctuation character; I'm using `|` to avoid conflicting with the `/` characters in the pattern.)

A more tcsh-specific, and possibly more efficient, way to do it is:

```
echo $VARIABLE:s|/opt/Application/||
```

It's likely to be more efficient because it's done within the shell and avoids invoking the external `sed` command.  On the other hand, the overhead of executing `sed` is unlikely to be significant.

Note carefully that the `:s` syntax is not supported in the original csh.  It is supported in tcsh and in some newer versions of csh.  If you want to do this portably, just use `sed`.

Comment: Fully agree with your assessment :-) But this should probably be a comment.

Comment: @Christian.K: I thought about that, but the first part does answer the question as stated.

Answer (score 1):

C-Shell has the built-in string modifiers that can do this with very little code:

```
echo $VARIABLE:h:t/$VARIABLE:t

string modifiers:
:h = remove the last directory (aka head)
:t = remove every directory except the last one (aka tail)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to get the 2 last names in a filename:

```
setenv VARIABLE /opt/Application/File/Version22
set lastfile=`basename $VARIABLE`
set prevpath=`dirname $VARIABLE`
set previousfile=`basename $prevpath`
set file=$previousfile/$lastfile
echo $file
```